# How can I implement an alias in .htaccess in Apache configuration?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I implement an alias in .htaccess in Apache configuration?
Thank U)

```
Alias /static "/var/www/core/static" 
<Location "/static"> 
    SetHandler None #
</Location>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `Alias` in an htaccess file. You can do something similar using mod_rewrite but you *can not alias to a folder outside of the document root*. That means, in your example, if `/var/www/core/static` isn't in your document root, then you can't link to it. The htaccess file is a "per directory" context, and has no way of knowing anything that is outside of the document root.

The mod_rewrite way works something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /core/static [L]
```

Assuming that `/core/static` is inside your document root. If not, there's nothing you can do with an htaccess file.

Comment: /var/www/ root is a directory, but the record type is not working <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/entry_panel/styles.css">